# SSRS 2008 - Using javascript to encode a URL with an ampersand

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Slightly confusing title, but I'm stumped nonetheless.

I have a clickable link that will open your default mail client (in this case, ours is Outlook), and format a clickable URL. It works great 99% of the time unless the URL has an ampersand in it. I've replaced the & with %26 and & with no luck. The URL still cuts off where the ampersand is.

In SSRS, I have this setup as a hyperlink expression

```
=iif(Fields!EmailShippingURL.Value="URL Unavailable" OR Fields!ShippingURL.Value="URL Unavailable" OR isNothing(Fields!EmailShippingURL), "javascript:(alert('The shipment info cannot be processed. There is either no email address for this contact or invalid shipping information.'))", "javascript:void(window.open('"+ Fields!EmailShippingURL.Value + "','_blank'))")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the chr() function -

```
"javascript:void(window.open('"+ replace(Fields!EmailShippingURL.Value, "&", chr(38)) + "','_blank'))"
```

Or the javascript escape function -

```
"javascript:void(window.open('"+ replace(Fields!EmailShippingURL.Value, "&", "'+escape('&')+'") + "','_blank'))"
```